# Filter 2 arrays to check if parent child

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, json

I have first array -

```
let parent = [
    {
     id:1,
     value:"ABC",
    },
    {
     id:2,
     value:"DEF",
    },
    {
     id:3,
     value:"GHI",
    },
    {
     id:4,
     value:"JKL",
    },
    {
     id:5,
     value:"MNO",
    },
    {
     id:6,
     value:"PQR",
    },
    ]
```

And 2nd Array Object -

```
let child = [
{
 childid:1,
 value:"ABC",
},
{
 childid:2,
 value:"DEF",
},
{
 childid:10,
 value:"GHI",
},
]
```

From parent array I want to select all those elements whose id matches with childid from child array.

I tried -

```
parent.filter(x=>x.id==child.each(y=>y.childid))
```

But its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do it

```js
let parent = [
    {
     id:1,
     value:"ABC",
    },
    {
     id:2,
     value:"DEF",
    },
    {
     id:3,
     value:"GHI",
    },
    {
     id:4,
     value:"JKL",
    },
    {
     id:5,
     value:"MNO",
    },
    {
     id:6,
     value:"PQR",
    },
    ]
 
 let child = [
{
 childid:1,
 value:"ABC",
},
{
 childid:2,
 value:"DEF",
},
{
 childid:10,
 value:"GHI",
},
]


let result = parent.filter(p => child.some(a =>  a.childid == p.id ))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

using [Flatmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ...

```js
let parent = [{
    id: 1,
    value: "ABC",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "DEF",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "GHI",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: "JKL",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: "MNO",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    value: "PQR",
  },
]
let child = [{
    childid: 1,
    value: "ABC",
  },
  {
    childid: 2,
    value: "DEF",
  },
  {
    childid: 10,
    value: "GHI",
  },
]
const res = parent.flatMap(x => child.filter(y => y.childid === x.id))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work

```
parent.filter(p => child.some(c => c.childid === p.id))
```

Wat happens is

1. For each element in parent array, find the corresponding element in the child array
2. If it exists the filter will see it as truthy and keep the parent element, if not it will be falsy and filter wil discard it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2):

```
const filterResult = parent.filter(x => child.some(y => y.childid == x.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `reduce` function along with a `forEach` to loop through the child elements and compare against the parent.

```
const result = parents.reduce((acc, parent) => {
  children.forEach((child) => {
    if (parent.id === child.childid) {
      acc.push(parent);
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result); // [{"id":1,"value":"ABC"},{"id":2,"value":"DEF"}]
```

```js
const parents = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'ABC',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'DEF',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'GHI',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: 'JKL',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: 'MNO',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    value: 'PQR',
  },
];

const children = [{
    childid: 1,
    value: 'ABC',
  },
  {
    childid: 2,
    value: 'DEF',
  },
  {
    childid: 10,
    value: 'GHI',
  },
];

const result = parents.reduce((acc, parent) => {
  children.forEach((child) => {
    if (parent.id === child.childid) {
      acc.push(parent);
    }
    return acc;
  });

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

[MDN Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)